# OpenCV: Assigning to Mat of type int16_t gives all zeros

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have the following code:

```
string filename = "frame_00003_depth.bin";

int16_t* depth_img = loadDepthImageCompressed(filename.c_str());

Mat depth_img_meters = Mat(480, 640, CV_16UC1);


for(int row = 0; row < 480; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < 640; col++){
        depth_img_meters.at<int16_t>(row, col) = depth_img[(640*row + col)]  * 0.001;


        cout << depth_img_meters.at<int16_t>(row,col)<< "meters" <<  endl;  

    }
}
```

I have checked that the array `int16_t* depth_img` has values in it greater than 100, however when assigning to the `Mat` here it prints all zeros

Comment: You are multiplying the values by 0.001, so 100 * 0.001 would be 0.1 and would get truncated to zero. Do you have values greater than 1000 in `depth_img`?

Comment: That was the problem. If you answer I will accept

Comment: In the future, @Aly, when you have unexpected behavior from a line of code, break the line of code down into individual steps (each on their own line).  Set up assertions after each step (using an `Assert` macro of some kind), and maybe even dump state to `std::cout` to describe what is happening.  At the least, this would have made it clear that your problem wasn't in the "assign to matrix element" component, but in the "what value am I assigning" component of the line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a truncation problem to me.

You are multiplying the values in `depth_img` by 0.001, which means the numbers are getting converted to floating point and then back to `int16_t` in the assignment process. This means that any values less than 1000 in `depth_img` will be truncated to zero in `depth_img_meters`

Any time you are dealing with different data types you have to watch out for errors associated with this sort of implicit conversion during assignment.